# Android Activity Refreshing On Rotation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-context

I'm an experienced .NET dev, but this is my first Android app and it's driving me nuts!

It's a countdown timer which works fine, but when you rotate the screen it reinitialised the activity which zeroed and stopped the count down.

This is what I tried;
I got rid of the CountDownTimer object and instead created a class internal to the activity which extended AsyncTask so it ran on a separate thread...  No change.
I figured being an internal class it's being reinitialised with the activity.

Here's what I tried next;
I made the class an external one.  The Activity passes its Context to the class and the onProgressUpdate & onPostExecute run public functions on the context to update the activity's UI.
Again, this works fine until you rotate it...  Aaaargh!

However, I discovered that the async class is still running but the UI doesn't change because (I think) the activity now has a different context to the one the async class has reference to.

So that's where I am.  Each solution fixes one problem & creates another.
Do I need to somehow maintain the context or am I starting to chase my own tail?

Any help will be gratefully appreciated!

Ta.
Barry

Comment: Thanks guys, that's incredibly helpful!  I reckon that's sorted my problem - I just need to unpick my code to be more structured & I'll be able to make use of your advice...  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I discovered that the async class is still running but the UI doesn't change because (I think) the activity now has a different context to the one the async class has reference to.

Nice guess. You have to handle the `Activity's lifecycle`, if you want to keep the computed data since whenever you rotate the device, the activity is getting recreated thus `onCreate()` is getting called **without** saving the previous computed data. You have to override `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` in order to save your computations. Take a look at the [Activity's LifeCycle documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and [Reto Meier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android/151940#151940), I think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

In your `CountDownTimer` implement `onTick`:

```
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    // something like this:
    this.millisUntilFinished = millisUntilFinished;
}
```

In your `Activity` implement `onSaveInstanceState`:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // something like this:
    savedInstanceState.putLong("millisUntilFinished", millisUntilFinished);
}
```

also in `onCreate` and `onStart` re-setup your `CountDownTimer`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        millisUntilFinished = savedInstanceState.getLong("millisUntilFinished");
    }

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    timer = new MyCountDownTimer(millisUntilFinished, 100); 
    timer.start();
}
```

Don't copy this code verbatim, there are a few details missing/assumptions made that will be different in your code, but it could look something like this.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Try_me34 is good, but here are some other ways to save and restore data (can't post them as a comment):

Try overriding the `onPause` method and save the process to a secondary class (a Timer, maybe) and then restore it overriding `onResume`.

Another option is to save it as a preference:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("nameOfFile", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putInt("name", value);
editor.putString("nameForString", value);
```

And then load it:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("nameOfFile", MODE_PRIVATE);
int i = prefs.getInt("tag", 0);
String s = prefs.getString("tag", "defaultValue");
```